# I want to deploy my node js server on cyclic.sh

Tags: javascript, typescript

From where should i get the certificate and key in cyclic , what shouild i write on the place of const certPath = process.env.SSL_CERT_PATH;
const keyPath = process.env.SSL_KEY_PATH

My index.ts file is

```
import express from "express";
import pkg from 'colyseus';
import cors from "cors";
import { config } from "dotenv";
import { WebSocketTransport } from "@colyseus/ws-transport";
import { MyRoom } from "./rooms/MyRoom.js";
import { createServer } from "https";
import * as fs from 'fs';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);
import path from "path";
const { Server } = pkg;

config();

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

const portString = process.env.PORT || "3005";
const port = parseInt(portString, 10);

function corsMiddleware(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
    next();
}

app.use(corsMiddleware);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send({ title: "Welcome" })
})

app.get("/matchmake/joinOrCreate/GameRoom", (req, res) => {
    // Your logic for handling the GET request goes here
    console.log("Game Room request")
    res.status(200).send("Handling GET request for /matchmake/joinOrCreate/GameRoom");
});

const certPath = process.env.SSL_CERT_PATH;
const keyPath = process.env.SSL_KEY_PATH

const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(keyPath),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(certPath)
};

console.log("Using options : ", options);

const server = createServer(options, app);

let gameServer = new Server({
    transport: new WebSocketTransport({
        server,
        verifyClient: (info: any, next: any) => {
            next(true);
        },
    }),
});

gameServer.define('GameRoom', MyRoom);
gameServer.listen(port).then(() => {
    console.info("Game started and listening on port", port);
})
    .catch((err: any) => {
        console.error("Failed to listen on port" + err)
    })
console.info(`Server running on port ${port}`);
```

i tried this

const certPath = process.env.SSL_CERT_PATH;
const keyPath = process.env.SSL_KEY_PATH

from where should i get certificate and key